# How big of an impact requests per second and memory consumption can have on costs

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform, apache2, php7

Gentlemen,

We are in a bit of a debate here. An old one, php framework or no framework. We ran some tests and core php clearly takes the lead in handing requests per second and better memory consumption.

We are building an enterprise level micro services based app. So the question is, when it comes to operating costs of server, how big the difference could be if we use a framework which can handle 1k requests per second, vs no framework which can handle 7k requests.

Framework in question is laravel

Our server is centos, apache, mysql on GCP

Comment: I suspect you have your numbers backwards in your second paragraph. All in all, server costs are often low compared with the cost of the people for coding, maintenance, and problem solving. I suggest you look at whole of life costs, not just server costs.

Comment: Obviously the cost is multiplied by seven, approximately. But as Tim pointed out, the difference is far less than even the cost of a single developer. It likely costs more to debate about it than to simply write code efficiently, regardless of framework.

Answer (score 1):

Develop with whatever you find easiest to create and maintain the solution you want. Abstraction layers might be slower, but they tend to add flexibility and utility.

Build in performance monitoring that tracks the user experience. Run reports for your infrastructure costs. When these metrics show unacceptable trends, then optimize.